# Trouble accessing Apache NiFi UI behind AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-nifi

I am having an issue setting up Apache NiFi behind AWS ALB. I can currently access the UI when hitting the server's public IP address directly but have been unsuccessful getting it working behind the ALB. It does work behind the ALB when HTTPS is not setup in NiFi. It fails to work when NiFi https is enabled with certificate authentication. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The ALB is not going to pass the client certificate to the server. If you want to use use client certificate authentication, you will have to switch to an NLB with TCP passthrough, at which point the NiFi server will be serving an SSL certificate directly to the client, and the client's certificate will be passed through the load balancer to the Nifi server.